# TOTP 2FA codes for login to GitHub are not working anymore since Daylight Saving Time occurred

Tags: github, two-factor-authentication, totp, aegis

I'm using this mobile app on Android: https://getaegis.app/ which is using [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-Time_Password) for connecting to, e.g. GitHub and some other web apps (e.g. a self hosted Django one for example).

Since this morning, nothing is working anymore. I'm not able to log in these platforms, getting messages such as "Invalid token" or "Two-factor authentication failed." (this latter being on GitHub).

I'm wondering if this is kind of related to the local time which changed to Daylight Saving Time (+1h) this week-end.

I cannot find any settings related to time in the app.

Do you know how I can fix it (if possible) and if not, if there is something I can do to properly recover my accounts?

Comment: Perhaps you can extract the secrets for your accounts from the app and input them to another app to see the difference? It looks like the app does backups at least, so maybe that could help.

Comment: Just to verify this, I faked the phone's time by changing its time zone to my local winter time! And guess what? It works now... But the time is not synchronized with the internet, and I may suffer a drift in the future. And if this drift becomes more important than the expiration time of the generated password, I'll get kicked off my accounts until next winter (unless I try to manually fix the time of course). :D